# How to make coding language?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors

I want to make my own coding language and first what i wanted to make was a simple hello world.
I made code like this(compiler):

```
    f=open('compRead.upb')
line='dum'
for i in range(10):
    ifFunc=i+1
    line=f.readline(i)
    if line=='out:{':
        print(f.readline(ifFunc))
    
input()
```

(compRead.upb):

```
    out:{
Hello, world!
}
```

But its just not printing anything.
If you want to know why i want to make my own coding language then i'm just experimenting whit anything.
(two weeks ago i wanted to make my own os)

Now i edited code to this:

```
f=open('compRead.upb')
line='dum'
OutTRUE='false'
for i in range(10):
    
    line=f.readline(i)
    if OutTRUE=='true':
        print(line)
    if line=='out:{':
        OutTRUE='true'
    
input()
```

But problem still is the same.

Comment: If it isn't printing anything, then line=='out:{' is false. You should check what line actually is

Comment: It's because of the tab in front of out, and this isn't a good way of doing things. Maybe check out this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eythq9848Fg, there are many resources for writing interpreters out there.

Comment: If you are actually going to try to write your own language, then you really need to learn to debug a program like this yourself. Did you try checking to see what the values for `line` are? Tried comparing them to `'out:{'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to get rid of all the whitespace in the line. So
`if line.strip() == 'out:{':`. If you want to write a language, *do research*. Look up lexers, parsers, and the interpreter itself. Check out this great series by CodePulse: youtube.com/watch?v=Eythq9848Fg

And, based off the code you've written, you should not write a language at your skill level with Python.

Comment: @CALISVALIS1010 if this answered your question you should click that little check mark next to my answer